# Did China say that war with the US over the South China Sea dispute is now a "reality"?

Tags: politics, quotes, china

According to [this article from the Daily Star](http://www.dailystar.co.uk/news/latest-news/582878/China-US-Declare-War-Donald-Trump-South-Sea-Navy-Islands-Practical-Reality-Communist-Party), published on the 29th of January, 2017,

> CHINA has declared war with the US is now a “reality” as military
>   commanders rallied their forces to be ready for total conflict as
>   early as “tonight”.

Are there any reliable sources to corroborate that some Chinese authority made such a statement?

Comment: To summarise the confusingly-worded article: China is upset at the US, and has postured that its military is ready to fight at any time if necessary, and that the USA should not send three aircraft carriers. Are you asking if China sent such a message to the USA? Are you asking if the Chinese military is ready to start fighting within 12 hours? [What does that mean?] Are you asking if China could defeat 3 (or 10) aircraft carriers? [What evidence would you accept?]

Comment: @Oddthinking I'm asking whether China declared that war in the South China Sea is now a reality. Not sure how I could edit this to make it clearer.

Comment: @Oddthinking is it better now?

Comment: Okay, so the question is "Daily Star said China said [X was true]", and your question is "Did China say [X was true]?" and not "Is X true?"

Comment: @Oddthinking yes